# How to use Select INTO statement when table columns keep changing?

Tags: select, dynamic, powerbuilder

I want to use **Select INTO** statement for a table that keep changing number of columns.

**Select * FROM myTable** returns me the desired output but i dont know how to use same select statement in powerbuilder with INTO because i dont know how many columns will be there in myTable and i dont even know what will be the names for those columns.

Names and numbers of columns varies so i think array can be used but how to use it i have no idea. Is it possible? is there any other way to solve this problem?

PowerBuilder 12.5 / MSSQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **select * from myTable** as your SQL string and [create a DataWindow dynamically](https://www.rgagnon.com/pbdetails/pb-0071.html) . You can use the Describe() functions to get the column count (and optionally names, database column source, data types), and GetItem*() with column numbers to retrieve the data.

Please keep in mind that while preparing for change sounds good, like all design choices, it comes with trade offs. In this case, consider performance (creation of the DW requires extra trips to the database) and maintainability (troubleshooting a problem involving a dynamic DW is much harder than a static one; you’ll need to staff up with more advanced programmers). You might want to consider how often the table will change, and how likely it will be that the user will be **so** happy with the application that the occasional release with other changes would be a bad thing. (Not that I’ve *never* done this, but over 25 years in PB and dozens of clients, I can probably count the times on the fingers of one hand. For me, it’s a carefully considered last resort.)

Comment: The DB designer found it  easy to handle parameters in multiple columns instead of one column (with string parsing needed). The reason he told me was an easy way to supply values for parameters instead of looking for parameters in many coma separated key value pairs, neither he wanted another table. He wanted one row for both parent window parameters and same row for child parameters too. Sound like a pregnant parent and child is pregnant too with another child and so on. That idea of yours worked and i used it for one window to be parent and child at he same time.   Only one dynamic DW.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of Terry's answer you can use dot notation to determine the specifics on a datawindow object's data after retrieval.  So after you have dynamically created the datawindow and retrieved the data you can assign the data values to a structure.

From the PowerBuilder help:

> This example assigns all the data in dw_1 to the Any variable la_dwdata. The value assigned to la_dwdata is an array of data structures whose members match the column datatypes:

```
any la_dwdatala_
la_dwdata = dw_1.Object.Data
```

You can use the Classname() method to determine the datatype of each column if needed.

Comment: Many paths up the mountain. Those that stop reading at the first answer often lose.